# Can merge-sort algorithm be implemented in MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is it possible to implement merge-sort algorithm using MapReduce?
I am sceptic about this, because mappers or reducers cannot communicate with each other, but someone told me it is one of the crucial use cases for MapReduce(??).
I was searching for any implementation or even clue on how to do it, but i couldn't find anything.
I myself have no single clue on how to do it...
Any ideas?

@Edit
Yes. I know that MapReduce has sorting feature out of the box.
Is it possible to turn it off for example?

Answer (score 3):

Merge sort is what MapReduce does when the map and reduce function are unit functions. Look up **Terasort benchmark** to see more details.

Comment: Hmm this is nice suggestion, but anyway i took a look at it before asking the question. The question is, can i make my own custom sorting implementation using mapreduce?

Comment: You can overwrite the sorting algorithm

Answer (score 3):

Merge sort is the default feature of mapreduce no need to implement it and you cannot change the sorting method of mapreduce because the data comes from different nodes to a single point so the best algorithm that can be used here is the mergesort .What else you can do is specify your own comparator class to sort your keys in ascending or descending order.

```
job.setSortComparatorClass(YourClass.class);
```

Comment: Not sure if this is correct: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/PluggableShuffleAndPluggableSort.html